# jqGrid - Export contents of grid to Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, jqgrid, export

Using jQuery 1.9.1 & jqGrid 4.5.2.  Using web browsers IE8 & Firefox (predominantly IE8).  I cannot use ASP.NET or PHP.

I have a jqGrid that I am displaying on a page.  It has several columns, including a couple that are hidden.  The visible columns are (across the page) - 2 integer fields, 2 text fields, a date-time field, and a text field.  Hidden columns are 1 text field & 1 integer field.  Some of the text fields could have punctuation in them, or symbols.

Is there a method in jqGrid that I'm not aware of that will allow you to export it to excel?

A less preferable method would be to select all items in the jqGrid & then to copy & paste them into excel.  That method though isn't without issues either.  Pasting as HTML alters the formatting, pasting as text puts everything as 1 column, pasting to match Destination formatting works, but all are dependent on being able to select the contents of the grid & none of them get the hidden columns.

Is there a good (and relatively easy) way to get the contents of the jqGrid from the web page into Excel?  To get the hidden columns in the output would be a bonus.

As noted above, I cannot use ASP.NET or PHP.  I would prefer not to add an additional library, but would add a plugin if it helped to achieve the end result.

Would appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046524/need-to-export-to-csv-all-of-the-data-that-is-in-jqgrid

Comment: @pax162 - I can't use ASP.NET or PHP with this.  Unless I am not understanding something from the page you linked to, they were using PHP.

Comment: You can check this link. [Export to excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898895/export-jqgrid-data-into-excel-pdf-with-currency-format)